# Use cURL to save dynamic excel file from url

Tags: php, curl

I have a secure site that I login to using cURL.  This works fine.  I then call a second url with post data that will create an excel file that is returned to the browser.  It takes a second or two for the file to be created and sent back to the browser.  I've played around with the cURL settings but can't quite get it to save the file to my server.  Below is the script I am trying:

```
    //curl login url
    $login_url = 'https://url.com/control_panel.php';

    //init curl
    $ch = curl_init();

    //Set the URL to work with
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login_url);

    // ENABLE HTTP POST
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    //Set the post parameters
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'username='.$username.'&password='.$password);

    //Handle cookies for the login
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');

    //return results not true/false
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    //execute the request (the login)
    $store = curl_exec($ch);

    //the login is now done and you can continue to get the protected content.

    //set the URL to the protected file
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://url.com/buildexcel');

    //form variables we want
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
    $post_data = array(
        'from_month' => date('n', $start_date),
        'from_day' => date('j', $start_date),
        'from_year' => date('Y', $start_date),
        'to_month' => date('n', $end_date),
        'to_day' => date('j', $end_date),
        'to_year' => date('Y', $end_date),
        'all_leagues' => 1,
        'practices' => 1,
        'export' => 'Export Schedule'
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data); 

    //execute the request
    $content = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    //save the data to disk
    $file = './uploads/excel_'.time().'.csv';
    file_put_contents($file, $content);
```

Any help would be great.  I have tried other methods with no luck either:

```
    $fp = fopen ($local_file, 'w+');

    //set the URL to the protected file
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://url.com/buildexcel');

    //form variables we want
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);       
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, ""); 
    $post_data = array(
        'from_month' => date('n', $start_date),
        'from_day' => date('j', $start_date),
        'from_year' => date('Y', $start_date),
        'to_month' => date('n', $end_date),
        'to_day' => date('j', $end_date),
        'to_year' => date('Y', $end_date),
        'all_leagues' => 1,
        'practices' => 1,
        'export' => 'Export Schedule'
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data); 

    //execute the request
    $content = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
```

After this code if saves the file but it is the html from the page not the excel that is sent to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

try this >>> this code to get data from url but with GET Http request i think you only need (===the important part===)

```
$ch = curl_init();

$csrf_token = $this->getCSRFToken($ch);// this function to get csrf token from website if you need it
$ch = $this->signIn($ch, $csrf_token);//signin function you must do it and return channel
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);// if file large
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://your-URL/anything");

$return=curl_exec($ch);
//=== the important part === to save file
$destination ="files.xlsx";
if (file_exists( $destination)) {
    unlink( $destination);
}
$file=fopen($destination,"w+");
fputs($file,$return);
if(fclose($file))
{
    echo "downloaded";
}
curl_close($ch);
```